# Map 1D Dataset to 3D Space

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, mapping, k-means

I've a 1D data set as follows

```
19, 23, 35, 39, 39, 48, 48, 72, 83, 91, 151, 152, 153, 156, 158, 160, 250, 340, 490
```

I want to get the most frequent range out of this value set. I thought of applying k-mean clustering algorithm and take the cluster with most elements. I use `k = sqrt(n/2)`

The output should be `151 - 160`

When search I saw few articles suggest that applying k-means clustering for a 1d data-set is not a good idea. Therefore I thought of map 1d data-set to 3d space. What I did was simply assume y and z co-ordinates of as 0  for each data point.

Is there a better way to map this data-set to 3d space?
Or is there a better way to get the most frequent range out of 1d data-set?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you add a dimension you make life more difficult, so moving from 1 to 3 dimensions is not likely to make live easier.

I would sort the data into order and then think about ways to move along it from right to left. For example, move pointers so that they have a window of N items between them and find the position where the difference between the value at the left end of the window and the value at the right end of the window is smallest.

If you really want to use k-means like clustering you can use dynamic programming on an array of sorted values to get an exact answer. Work from left to right and at each point compute, for i=1..k, the lowest cost way to divide up the values to that point into i clusters. You can work out the best answer at position N for i clusters by considering the cost, for each m, of making m..N a single cluster and looking at the answers for m-1 to work out the best cost of dividing the previous values up into i-1 clusters.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But I didn't get that moving part. I saw that I can use Jenks classifier for a 1D dataset, rather than increasing dimensions. Is that same what you mean?

Comment: I'm not a fan of Jenk's classifier (I'd prefer dynamic programming) but it's what people expect and are used to so it makes sense to use it. The moving part was because I wasn't sure what you were asking for. It was to answer questions such as "where are the ten values which fit within the smallest possible range?"

Comment: hmm. In my example range is 151-60. Coz that is the smallest range which consist of most numbers. I can't pick a fixed window size :/ that is  the problem. That is why I thought of using clustering. Do you have any idea how to tackle that sort of problem?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne: Why is 150-160 the best answer? Why not 150-148 or 150-146 which have better densities?

Comment: @Thusitha Thilina Dayratne I don't know how to tackle your problem because I don't know how your data are generated and I don't know why you need to pick a range, so I don't know what answers are good and what answers are bad. One way of working out what a good answer is to work out how much money it would save or cost you.  One way of testing ideas when you know how data is generated is to write programs to generate test data where you know the right answer and see how your ideas do on this data.

Comment: @MOehm yeah I agree with you. I didn't notice that before. I just tried to do clustering and check if that can help me to figure out the ranege.

Comment: @mcdowella. YEs you are correct. Sorry for asking that idiotic question :D